# retrieve json from a refreshing page using ajax

Tags: ajax, json, refresh

I have index.php page which makes a ajax call to thread.php by sending the variable "dateposted". The thread.php returns a json which is being looped through in my index.php and the last value is sent back into the ajax call again. All this works fine. 
However, the problem i face is when i put thread.php in autorefresh using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
```

When i do this, the returned response in my ajax call includes this and the json results which throws my looping of the json array off. I can remove the above code since i need thread.php to be constantly refreshing to poll data from the server. How do i get around this issue:

For reference:
thread.php

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
if(!isset($_GET['dateposted']))
{ $lastpost = 0; 
}
else
{$lastpost= $_GET['dateposted'];}



  $latestmsgs = retrieveNewMsgs($lastpost,$currtime);
  ?>

 <?php echo json_encode($latestmsgs);?>
```

index.php

```
var returnValue = (function() {
    var  dateposted = null;
    return function() {
        $.get("thread.php", { "lastMessage":  dateposted }, function(result) {
        if(result) {

                        for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {

                            var msgs = result[i];
                            var newDiv = $("<div><img src='" + msgs[0] +"'/>" + msgs[2] + msgs[3] + msgs[4] + msgs[5] + "</div><br>");

                           $('#chatContents').append(newDiv);

                        }

                }

           dateposted = result[result.length-1][5];
        }, "json");
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) function to execute some javascript code at regular intervals of time that you define. So remove the meta refresh tag and place your AJAX call inside `setInterval`:

```
// poll the server every 10 seconds for new data
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.get("thread.php", ...
}, 10000);
```

Comment: So instead of <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2"> I use the setInterval function in the thread.php?

Comment: I found where i was making the error. I wasnt catching the null pointer exception for the array. So it kept going back to 0. And returning the entire list again. I thought it was because it wasnt refreshing. Thanks for the help